# <java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver> when connecting SQL in background via window scheduler

Tags: database, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation, sqljdbc

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver>
When connecting a SQL server through Selenium webdriver(eclipseIDE), running as  a background window service(**although connection is a success in the foreground**)

OS:Window server 2012....
**sqljdbc4-2.0.jar** path is included in the classpath.....
Window Firewall is off.....
Running a batch file as a window service which is calling a testng.xml to execute classes.....Even tried by including the sqljdbc4-2.0.jar path in PATH(system environment variable)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just resolved it : the java package should contain all the external libraries.
I had a ANT based framework in which all external jars were referred from lib folder(present within the package)

But there was one jar(`sqljdbc4-2.0.jar`)for which I gave the reference from some other package, and this created the issue.

Comment: You should include further informations about the resolution of your problems in order to help people who will face it later.

Comment: Your java package should contain all the external libaries....I had a ANT based framework in which all external jars were referred from lib folder(present within the package).....There was one jar(sqljdbc4-2.0.jar )for which i gave the reference from some other package......and because of it I was having this issue

Comment: I've edited your answer to include your comment. You should mark this answer as valid now :)

Comment: Thanks @MichaëlAzevedo